# How to update react-native iOS app to use iOS 15 SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, xcode13

I got an email form app store saying **iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 15 SDK or later**. I'm not sure how do I do that.

I'm currently using **Xcode 13.2.1** and **react-native 0.64.0**

[image: H]

Comment: The problem was the version of Xcode I was using in Github actions.  Updating it to use the latest macOS fixed the issue.